# Android View clipped despite all it's parents being set to not clip

Tags: android, view, clipping

**Background:**

It's the classic problem of adding a view and moving it outside parent when it gets clipped. My hierarchy is as follows:

View(any type) -> added to a RelativeLayout -> son of a Linear Layout -> which is added to an Activity using addContentView(...)

I have programmatically added the view into view hierarchy and then moved a little outside parent rect (I tried setTranslationY(-200f), setY(), TranslationAnimation, ..).

**The Problem:**

The view is partially clipped.

**Additional information:**

- I'm sure the view is of correct size, as the transparent/clipped part can be seen in Layout Inspector as a transparent frame.
- The original view added is being cut regardless of which view type it is (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, a custom Canvas view, a View view.
- The parent view is added to an Activity using

> mActivity.addContentView(MyLinearLayout, getLayoutParams());

The layout params given are with exact dimensions, something like 500, 500.

- I've tried running a function after adding the view that goes through the view and all its parents and disables clipping. Also invalidates all views along the way.

> private void setAllParentsClip(View v, boolean enabled) {
>       while (v.getParent() != null && v.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
>           ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
>           viewGroup.setClipChildren(enabled);
>           viewGroup.setClipToPadding(enabled);
>           v = viewGroup;
>
> ```
>     v.invalidate();
> } }
> ```

Comment: It's worth checking if there is another view group/view in the LinearLayout (another child of the LinearLayout) which has been added later (or is "lower" in the xml file) which obscures your RelativeLayout's translated children.